# How to clear text-decoration of :before in a.class css on hover?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I use Font Awesome to put an icon before my hyperlink. I have a css for my hyperlink:

```
a.cancel {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.71;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #eb1700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.cancel:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; 
  content: "\f057";
  padding: 0 4px 0px 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a.cancel:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.cancel:hover:before {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

Unfortunately, the text-decoration isn't removed under my icon when hovered. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to fix that, but here is how I usually proceed:

Set `display: inline-block` to the link, then `float: left` to its pseudo-element.

```css
a.cancel {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.71;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #eb1700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block; /* + */
}

a.cancel:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; 
  content: "\f057";
  padding: 0 4px 0px 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  float: left; /* + */
}

a.cancel:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.cancel:hover:before {
  text-decoration: none; /* You can remove this line */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="cancel">hello</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed.
Unfortunately, my icon isn't aligned properly now. It isn't centered vertically anymore...

Comment: You can simply use a `line-height` value to center your icon.

Comment: Also a problem; if I have an element :after, and I give it "float: right", there's really a great gap from my text...

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you provide a demo? JSFiddle maybe.

Comment: Never mind; it was an error in my code. Conclusion: your code works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit on your HTML here. Assuming there is no additional HTML in your A tag, the short answer is: you can't have the text-decoration apply to only part of the A tag via CSS. It applies to all of the A tag or not. The :hover is triggering on the A tag. The :before isn't truly a separate DOM element. The A:hover is triggering regardless of if you're over the :before portion or the regular portion, if that makes sense.

However, if don't mind adding a little extra HTML inside your A tag, you can have the underline apply only to that element:

```
<a class="cancel" href="http://example.com"><i>http://example.com</i></a>

a.cancel:hover i {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The above will tell it to put the underline only in the internal tag, not the whole A tag. You can use whatever inline tag you want, such as span, etc. This may not be what you want, but without some sort of separation, you can't have the A:hover apply only to the text and not to the :before. It's all one DOM element. If you inspect it in Chrome (and others), you'll see the ::before *inside* the A container.

Comment: As Quentin posted above, you can shift the ::before element outside from the A tag by changing the display and the float settings. But that is changing the layout significantly.